# Recive byte[] in ajax and save it

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I have web service that build for me PDF file  and send back byte[] (delete the file from server) ,
and then i need to save/open it on Pc when ajax recive byte[] .

My webService

```
 [Route("ConvertHtmlToPdfAndDownload")]
    [HttpPost]
    [HttpGet]
    public byte[] ConvertHtmlToPdfAndDownload(JObject data)
    {
         //some code

            System.IO.FileStream dd = System.IO.File.OpenRead(PdfPath);
            Bytes = new byte[dd.Length];
            dd.Read(Bytes, 0, Bytes.Length);
            dd.Close();
            File.Delete(PdfPath);
            return Bytes;

        }
```

And my ajax function where i need to save it or open

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(ConvertHtmlToPdfAndSendEmail),
            dataType: 'json',
            url:"http://testservices.xx/ConvertHtmlToPdfAndDownload",
            contentType: 'application/octet-stream'


            success: function (result) {
          //How to save it or open 
            },
            error: function (req, err) {

            }
        })
```